# How to read many files from multipe folders in MATLAB?

Tags: matlab

I have many folders containing multiple files. I want my code to read all of the files from one folder, set them in one file, then go to the next folder and do this again. My files have one column with many rows (equal for each folder).

Comment: What type of file do you have?

Comment: How are the folders structured? Are you looking for a recursive folder or are they all from a folder list? Perhaps post a screenshot of your folder structure?

Answer (score 0):

You will want to read up on MATLAB's `dir` function.

http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/dir.html?refresh=true

Comment: You should explain with some code and a loop to OP's specifications (which I should add needs to be clarified).